# Funky derivative of trace of matrix with composition

Tags: matrix-calculus

Let's say we have:

- $z_i$ a vector in $\mathbb{R}^k$
- $W$ a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{d, k}$
- and $\Psi$ a invertible diagonal matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{d, d}$

I know that for ex (matrixcookbook):

$\frac{\delta Tr\ z_i^T {W}^T \Psi^{-1}Wz_i}{\delta W} = 2 \Psi^{-1}Wz_iz_i^T$

and:

$\frac{\delta Tr\ z_i^T {W}^T \Psi^{-1}x_i}{\delta W} = \psi^{-1}x_iz_i^T$

Now let s write $W^2 = (w_{i,j}^2)$, the matrix with squared elements of W.

How to compute $\frac{\delta Tr\ z_i^T {W^2}^T \Psi^{-1}W^2z_i}{\delta W}$ and $\frac{\delta Tr\ z_i^T {W^2}^T \Psi^{-1}x_i}{\delta W}$ ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\ga{\grad{\a}{W}}
\def\gb{\grad{\b}{W}}
$For typing convenience, name the scalar functions $\{\a,\b\}$. You have already done most of the hard work by calculating their gradients
$$\eqalign{
\ga &= 2 \Psi^{-1}Wz_iz_i^T \qquad\quad
\gb &= 2 \Psi^{-1}x_iz_i^T \\
}$$
Instead of changing the meaning of $W\!,\,$ introduce a new matrix $U$ and express $W$ in terms of this new variable using the elementwise/Hadamard product
$$\eqalign{W &= U\odot U}$$
Use the known gradient to write the differential of the scalar function in terms of $W$, then change the independent variable from $W\to U$, and recover the gradient with respect to $U$.

For example
$$\eqalign{
d\a &= \LR{\ga}:dW \\
   &= \LR{\ga}:\LR{2U\odot dU} \\
   &= 2U\odot\LR{\ga}:dU \\
\grad{\a}{U} &= 2U\odot\LR{\ga} \\
}$$
where a colon has been used as a concise product notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
This product plays nicely with the Hadamard product
$$\eqalign{
A:(B\odot C) &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}C_{ij} \\
  &= (A\odot B):C \\
  &= (C\odot A):B \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot @greg ! Nevertheless I am not sure I understand the first line of your example: $d\alpha = (\frac{\delta \alpha}{\delta W} ): dW$